# authetification by spring security costum login page jsf

Tags: spring, jsf, authentication, primefaces, spring-security

I'm creating a custom login form using spring security 3.1, primefaces 5.0,jsf 2.0, and the application works exactly, but the problem is that when I want to autheticate I must use the URL. I need the authentication page to appear when I execute the project and dispatche to the suitable page.
Can someone help on this?

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring/security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Enable Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<!-- Allow login pages with JSF which redirects to security check, therefore we have to add the forward entry here -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

LoginController.java

```
@ManagedBean(name="loginController")
@RequestScoped
public class LoginController implements PhaseListener {

protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

/**
 *
 * Redirects the login request directly to spring security check.
 * Leave this method as it is to properly support spring security.
 * 
 * @return
 * @throws ServletException
 * @throws IOException
 */
public String doLogin() throws ServletException, IOException {
    ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest) context.getRequest())
            .getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_check");

    dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) context.getRequest(),
            (ServletResponse) context.getResponse());

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();

    return null;
}

public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see javax.faces.event.PhaseListener#beforePhase(javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent)
 * 
 * Do something before rendering phase.
 */
public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    Exception e = (Exception) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get(
            WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);

    if (e instanceof BadCredentialsException) {
        logger.debug("Found exception in session map: "+e);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put(
                WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION, null);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Username or password not valid.", "Username or password not valid"));
    }
}
public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
    return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
}
```

springsecurity.xml

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin.jsf" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/user.jsf" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    <!-- Custom login page -->
    <form-login login-page="/login.jsf" />

    <!-- Custom logout page -->
    <logout />
</http>

<!-- Use inline authentication provider. -->
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>

        <user-service>
            <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
              <user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER" />

        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

root-context.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-  package="de.slackspace.tutorials.customloginpage" />
```

Comment: Why are there managed bean and `PhaseListener` together? Instead, you  may want to have a separate login managed bean of a desired scope and your security configuration file appears to be incomplete. Are you finding some difficulties with authentication/authorization? It appears to be incomplete from the question.

Comment: there is no problem with authentication/authorization I just ask if there is any way to use the login page directly to determinate the user and his authorities , and send him to the suitable page

Comment: I got an impression that you want more than one login page. Apart from that, you can define a login success handler and implement the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` interface on a class of your choice & override its `onAuthenticationSuccess()` method where you can access a set of authorities using `Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());` where `Authentication` will be available as a parameter to the overridden method. You can then conditionally check, if the set contains a role such as `if (roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN"))` and redirect accordingly

Comment: You need to register this class in the security config file such as `<beans:bean id="loginSuccessHandler" class="a.b.LoginSuccessHandler"/>` and give its reference to `<form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="loginSuccessHandler" .../>`. (The namespace `beans` which you may be using in a different way - use it in your way. The login page will be the same for all users with any authority unless you explicitly need different login pages for different users having different authorities/roles).